# Changing an image in a listview

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm using the tutorial code at http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview and after modifying the code so that it builds under monodroid 4.2.3, I've extended it so that the list class looks like this

public class Animal
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

```
    public string Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Image
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int ImageCheck
    { get; set; }

    public bool Checked
    { get; set; }
}
```

With the ItemClick event code looking like this

```
// ViewGroup parent = listView;

    void listView_ItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = this.listAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
        var view = (e.View ?? this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.customlistitem, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;
        ImageView iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageChecked);
        if (item.Checked == false)
        {
            item.Checked = true;
            item.ImageCheck = Resource.Drawable.@checked;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Checked = false;
            item.ImageCheck = Resource.Drawable.checkbox;
        }
        iv.SetImageResource(item.ImageCheck);
    }
```

While this works in so far as if I add in

```
Console.WriteLine("Animal clicked = {0}", item.Name);
```

the emulator output will show the name of the animal clicked, the ImageView is always at the top of the list.

Is there a way to have the tick in the correct place (so for example, if I click on the 5th item. the 5th ImageView shows a tick or just a box)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way

```
ImageView iv = e.View.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageChecked);
```

Job done!